# A for loop launching on Jupyter is not working while other lines do

Tags: python, for-loop, anaconda, jupyter

I am facing the following error. I was working on an interactive session of Jupyter one hour ago. After I turned it on again I have tried to get back to the session and I found out that Jupyter was not able to show the output of a code anymore.

I have tried to restarted Anaconda and the Jupyter session again and the problem persisted just for a **for loop**, while other parts seem to work fine. Did anyone meet the same problem like this? Can anyone suggest what am I supposed to do?

```
div = [5,7]
div[0]

for num in range(1,42): 
    if num == 13:
        continue
        if num%div[0]==0:
            print(num, 'the number is divisible for 5')    
            if num%div[1]==0:
                print(num, 'the number is divisible for 7')
                if num%div[0]==0 and num%div[1]==1:
                    print(num, 'the number is divisible for both 5 and
```

Comment: Do you really want those `if` statements to be nested like that rather than sequential? Also -- please post code as code rather than as screenshot. It is hard for the readers of your question to experiment with an image of code.

Comment: There is no way for that code to produce any output, due to the messed-up indentation.

Comment: Edited as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is much too nested. If a number is not a multiple of 13 nothing at all happens since the program never gets to any of the other `if` statements and if it is a multiple 13 then it hits the `continue` statement. In either case, nothing is ever printed. You want something more like:

```
div = [5,7]
div[0]

for num in range(1,42): 
    if num == 13:
        continue
    if num%div[0]==0:
        print(num, 'the number is divisible for 5')    
    if num%div[1]==0:
        print(num, 'the number is divisible for 7')
    if num%div[0]==0 and num%div[1]==1:
        print(num, 'the number is divisible for both 5 and 7')
```

This gives output -- buggy output but still output. You have a typo with `num%div[1]==1`. Since this is evident homework, I'll leave the rest of the debugging as an exercise.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. Yes, actually the one you were referring to is a typo. I didn't fix it since the problem I was trying to figure out was to launch the code itself, in spite of the error. But thank you for you cleariness